# model for "has a" relationship where multiple tables can have a thing

Tags: database-design

I need to model an `smtp` server configuration for various entities that can send email, so I have a table with the settings for an `smtp` server.

For example: entities that send email are "rooms" and "servers" -- they live in separate tables since they have little in common, but they each refer to an optional email configuration.

While it is simple to have a `SmtpConfigId` in both the rooms and servers table, I cannot see how to have a cascading delete where, if the room or server is deleted, then its corresponding smtp configuration is also deleted.

Of course, I could replicate the smtp configuration fields for each entity table that can send an email, I think that the business logic for sending mail would be simplified if the email config is in its own table.

In addition to the email configuration, which is `1:1` between entities that send email, and their smtp configuration, there is also the question of form letters, which is `1:M`, and I would also like a cascading delete to clean up the form letters if the entity that created them is deleted.

Am I thinking about this problem in the right way, and what is a good way to model it?  on delete triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider modeling as a polymorphic relationship with one table being used for the config stuff with a smtp_type field to distinguish the types (room, server, etc.).

Comment: This is basically what I ended up with: an enum for ownertype and an ownerid field referencing the PK of the owning table.  Then, for each owning table (room, server, etc) I added an `after delete` trigger to cleanup the referenced items.